# Intuition about outer measures.

Tags: measure-theory

[Folland](https://i.stack.imgur.com/k8NpQ.png)
I have a question regarding this proof. First of all in the statement does he mean to use $\rho$ in the brackets right after summation, or did he mean $\mu$. I looked at the errata and still am not sure.

Furthermore, in the proof he claims that for a sequence of $A_j$ in the power set, we can always approximate them by elements of our elementary family with accuracy of $\epsilon/2^j$. This sounds very bizarre and i have a difficulty accepting this. What is the intuition behind this, and are we assuming that the elementary family contains all kinds of sets that cover?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

He definitely means $\sum \rho(E_j)$.

For the second point, his specific claim is that we can find some sets $E_j$ with $\sum \rho(E_j) \le \mu^*(A) + \varepsilon2^{-j}$. Why should this be true? Because $\mu^*$ is the infimum of all such sums. If we cannot find such a sum within $\varepsilon 2^{-j}$, it can't have been the infimum.

Comment: but couldnt it be that all the covers are too big, so even if we take the smallest one of these covers, it wont be within an epsilon, but much larger?

Comment: It's possible that none of the covers is exactly the size of the outer measure, but the outer measure is an infimum. If nothing were within $\varepsilon$ of the infimum, then we would have a lower bound that is $\varepsilon$ higher, contradicting our assumption that the first thing was an infimum.

Comment: right i see, its an epsilon within the infimum. So then we are taking that infimum, and then looking at that infimum+$\epsilon$. Ok got it thank you.

Comment: @Atherton In fact the proof of subadditivity as written does NOT work if  $\mu^*(A_k)=+\infty$ for some $k$. In this case, although $\mu^*(A_k)$ is  the infimum of all sums $\sum \rho(E_j^k)$ where $A\subseteq \bigcup_{j} E_j^k$, we CANNOT find such a sum within $\varepsilon 2^{-j}$ of $ \mu^*(A_k)$.  To correct the proof the case where $\mu^*(A_k)=+\infty$ for some $k$ needs to be treated separately (it is not difficult at all).